# How to set a localStorage item as function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, local-storage

I would like to set a localStorage item as a function, but when I do it gets saved as a string.

```
localStorage.getData = function (key="def") {
  let data = null;

  if (this[key] && !_this.isDataAvailableInList(this[key])) {
    data = this[key].data;
  }

  return data;
};
```

The above function get stored as string and not function.

Note: Kindly do not provide alternatives or other suggestions, I am well aware of alternatives and am curious to know how this works. I have not provided the entire context so lets just assume I am in need of setting a localStorage item as a function

Comment: you need always to pass static key "def"?

Comment: just eval the string (with a paren wrap or `0||` header) and out comes a function: `eval("(function(a,b){return a+b})")(6,4)`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately local storage is only about strings. Even arrays or other data are always converted to strings.

For most dead data without cycles you can use of course `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`, but in other cases or for code or other Javascript entities unsupported by JSON (like `Infinity` or `undefined`) you need to serialize and deserialize yourself.

Javascript provides `eval`, so you can store the function `f` converting it first to a string with `f+""` and get back the function with `eval(s)`.
This won't work with closures however and moreover you cannot even know if a function is indeed a closure or not in Javascript (so you cannot even raise an error if the impossible operation of serializing a closure is attempted).

Comment: Yeah I tried eval, but thanks for the detailed explanation. Can you please provide  a simple JSBin example? Since eval I tried seemed to be causing issues

Answer (score 1):

Convert the function into a string via `.toString()`. When you read it, convert it back to a function via `new Function(myString)`.

Example:

No pamameters:

`(new Function('var a = 0; return a + 1;'))() === 1`

With parameters:

`(new Function(['param0'],'var a = param0; return a + 1;'))(100) === 101`

Note: The scope of the original function will be lost.

Comment: Can you please provide a simple JSBin example? I couldn't get your example to work properly